# Origins or History of the Correlation matrix

Tags: math-history, correlation

Does anyone know any resources or websites which gives the history of a correlation matrix or the nearest correlation matrix problem in the financial world?

Comment: I know what a correlation matrix is, but not what the problem is that you refer to.  What is it?

Comment: @kimchilover as the questions states. If you know what a correlation matrix is (and it would help me if you know what it actually does in finance as I have no idea), more specifically the history/origns of a CM. Then please answer below. If you looking for information on the NCM problem see: https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/the-nearest-correlation-matrix/

Comment: @kimchilover the short hand is that a correlation matrix is made from stock data and has 4 main properties. For whatever reason bad data, etc... we can only satisfy (usally) 3/4 properties - thus giving us a "almost correlation matrix". The NCM problem is, as it sounds, using certain algorithms to find the closest CM to the "input matrix" (i.e. the almost CM) that we currently have. As to why we need this matrix and what it is used for in finance - I have no idea